# How to check out code from old version with Google docs add-on script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I made an add-on that worked on 05/21.

[image]

At some point between then and now it broke.

The old code is no longer in the revision history which only goes back to 05/22.

I have tested `version 1`, and it works, which means it's using the right code.

[image]

I can run this working version, but I don't know how I can re-open the code for it.

How do I view the code for `version 1` of my add-on?

**EDIT**

From @BryanP's comment, I've been informed that there is an existing request for this [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner&groupby=&sort=&id=2523).

Comment: To my knowledge, you can't :/ If this is a standalone project, you can do the coding in Eclipse and have that sync to github, or alternatively just copy and paste each file.

Comment: @JensAstrup I only use IntelliJ, so hopefully someone will make a plugin for this.

Comment: relates to [issue 2523](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=2523). star that to vote for an enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit round the houses, but you could:

- Create a test project
- include the older version of your library
- Use the debugger to step into the older version of the code and then copy and paste it somewhere safe.

I use this technique to poke around in the libraries I'm using.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this