# Finding an old version of a library in Google Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script

I was given a google spreadsheet to manage at work and the library that it is accessing. However, the spreadsheet uses an older version of the library, (there are currently 3 versions, and it uses version 2). Version 2 dates back to oct 11 2016, but if I go to the version editor of the library script, it only dates back till oct 13 2016. So is there a way I can recover the version through the spreadsheet or through the library itself that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Take a look at my answer to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33051601/how-to-check-out-code-from-old-version-with-google-docs-add-on-script/33076588#33076588 (please uptick if useful).

Comment: I am hitting the debugger, but getting no noticeable results, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I think that they changed the way the debugger works so it doesn't show my whole old code anymore. But let me know if I'm mistaken. Thank you!

Comment: Are you "stepping into" the library code?

Comment: I think this is the debugger? This is the result that is being thrown from the debugger, I get a portion of what looks like it could be the code, but it seems completely out of context.
Here is an image of my debugger after I follow your steps. 
https://pasteboard.co/8gItV5Bci.png

Comment: Follow something like this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pEb-93pDHWU) to work out how to use the debugger, find a function that calls the library from the script contained in your sheet (checking you are including the correct version of the library), and step into a library function. This will display the file containing the library.

Comment: Thanks for the video, and after watching it, I was able to find the step in tools, however, they are stepping me into the latest version of the library, not the version that the script I have is using. Which is quite unfortunate. I'll try doing it all again in a clean script.

Comment: If you go into Resources > Libraries in the script contained in the sheet you can select which version of the library to look at.

Comment: I'll try it again with a custom made library just to experiment with this, but when I cycle through the three version and I step into my library, each time, the code is the same, which is very confusing to me, because it works differently depending on the version when I run the code, but the step only shows the newest version, regardless of what I have set in Resources.

Comment: Do you have the "dev" button on (which will make it ignore the version number and always use the latest version of the library)?

Comment: I think I finally got it, thanks man for all the help and patience!

Comment: Well done. Glad I could help.